# Postgres SELECT Where clause conditionally applies arguments in a stored proc when they are NOT NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

We have a stored proc, called externally to feed the `sname`, `sssn`.

The where must be applied when sname and sssn are NOT NULL only.

**Desired Result**

**name** is provided as "John Doe" but **sssn** is blank then the query where **la.name** clause will be filter results.

The query attempted is as below. AND only works when both are provided.
OR doesn't do its job as well.

```
SELECT
    la.id,
    la.name,
    la.application_number,
    la.status,
    la.created_at
FROM
    loanapp_flattened_view la
WHERE
    la.name ILIKE '%' || sname || '%'
    AND la.ssn ILIKE '%' || sssn
```

Comment: Should it return the entire table when both params are NULL?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
WHERE (la.name ILIKE '%' || sname || '%' OR sname IS NULL) AND
      (la.ssn ILIKE '%' || sssn OR sssn IS NULL)
```

This ignores the parameter if it is `NULL`.

Comment: This closed and worked for us this way

** WHERE
      (la.name ILIKE '%' || sname || '%' OR sname = '') AND
      (la.ssn ILIKE '%' || sssn || '%' OR sssn = '')**

Comment: @KishorekumarNeelamegam . . . That doesn't make sense.  The only advantage to. your version over `la.name ILIKE '%' || sname || '%'` is that your version will pick up `NULL` values for `la.name`.  Do you have `NULL`s in those columns?

Answer (score 0):

or you can use `or` , however this returns result even if combination of name and sssn doesn't exists , it returns result for each match name and sssn separately:

```
SELECT
    la.id,
    la.name,
    la.application_number,
    la.status,
    la.created_at
FROM
    loanapp_flattened_view la
WHERE
    la.name ILIKE '%' || sname || '%'
    OR la.ssn ILIKE '%' || sssn
```